# Appointments in Calendar

Tags: calendar

I have an IMAC that I purchased in Japan in late 2009 annam currently using in the US.  My issue is with Calendar, there are appointments showing up that are in Japanese and that I cannot cancel or delete, any suggestions.

Comment: You need to look from which (external) Calender they come from. Look on the left to see which calendars subscription you have.

Comment: @Charlie Please edit your posted Question to enter a thoughtful title that describes your actual issue.

Answer (score 1):

Usually the appointments and other information comes from a Calendar that you signed up to.

Look on the left to see which ones you are signed up to and disable the one you do not want.